# Microsoft JScript runtime error: The value of the property 'a' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Tags: javascript, vb.net, undefined

Not sure why this error is being thrown, I'm not seeing how the function is defined incorrectly.

```js
//onclick method

HTMLButtonElement.addEventListener("click", a);

button.onClick = function () { a };

function a(parentIndex) {
    var strParam = toString(parentIndex);
    if (strParam.contains("Summary")) {
        alterStyleSummary(HTMLButtonElement, selectedTbody);
    }
    else {
        alterStyle(HTMLButtonElement, selectedTbody);
    }
}

//method selected if summary collapse button is clicked, hides or shows child tasks
function alterStyleSummary(button, selectedTbody) {
    var selectedTbody = document.getElementsByName(parentIndex);
    //changes background image of button to + or -
    if (button.class = "expand") {
        button.class = "collapse";
        selectedTbody.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        button.class = "expand";
        selectedTbody.style.display = '';
    }
}
//method selected if unassigned collapse button is clicked, hides or shows child tasks
function alterStyle(button, selectedTbody) {
    var selectedTbody = document.getElementById(parentIndex);
    //changes background image of button to + or -
    if (button.class = "expand") {
        button.class = "collapse";
        selectedTbody.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        button.class = "expand";
        selectedTbody.style.display = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: It's because old IE and some other old browsers won't let you use `.class` as a property identifier (since it's a future reserved word) so your function is never created because of the SyntaxError. Use `["class"]` or some other name like `_class` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the input. That was likely one problem, but now I'm getting other errors "button is not defined" and .contains is not a supported method. Any suggestions?

Comment: Here's the code in html that creates the button
            writer.Write("<td style='width: 10%; text-align:right'>" + "<button type= ""button""; class=""expand""; onclick=""a('" + parentIndex.ToString() + " Summary" + "')""></button>" + "</td>")

Comment: My suggestion is to heed the information given in those error messages and dubug your code.

Comment: @user3802272 Where are you declaring `button`? You seem to be using it before declaring it (`button.onClick = function () { a };`). Also, what do you expect `HTMLButtonElement.addEventListener("click", a);` to do?